# Android, alarmManager not repeating daily

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I have a method that sets a repeating notification using the following code:

```
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, selectedHour);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, selectedMinute);      
long triggerAtMillis = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 1, intent, 0);

alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, triggerAtMillis, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

However, the notification is only shown the first time it's supposed to go off. After that, no repeating. I can't seem to get it to work with other interval times either.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of **alarm.setRepeating(int type, long triggerAtMillis, long intervalMillis, PendingIntent operation)**, you need to use **alarm.set(int type, long triggerAtMillis, PendingIntent operation)**